# jetpack compose LazyLayout parameters is not Specified

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to develop a `LazyLayout` in jetpack compose

```
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@Composable
fun LazyLayout(
    itemsProvider: LazyLayoutItemsProvider!,
    modifier: Modifier! = Modifier,
    prefetchState: LazyLayoutPrefetchState? = null,
    measurePolicy: (@ExtensionFunctionType LazyLayoutMeasureScope.(Constraints) -> 
MeasureResult)?
): Unit
```

there is two necessary parameters, `itemsProvider` and `measurePolicy` and this is all information about `itemsProvider` parameter in document:

> @param itemsProvider provides all the needed info about the items which could be used to compose and measure items as part of [measurePolicy].

I don't know how to provide this parameter for `LazyLayout`.

any idea how it works?

Comment: Inspect `LazyColumn` source code for examples

Comment: @PylypDukhov sadly there is no example

Comment: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/d5b322800ac4e76bb69825147955beebee5eac63/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyList.kt#L102

Comment: in this document there is a `rememberItemsProvider` for providing `LazyLayoutItemsProvider` which is internal and can't be used

Comment: So copy all internal items to your project, inspect them and modify on demand

Comment: @PylypDukhov when do you think we can expect to documentation ?

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide only "itemsProvider" parameter by creating object like this:

```
LazyLayout(
    itemsProvider = object : LazyLayoutItemsProvider {
        override fun getContent(index: Int): @Composable () -> Unit {
            return {
                //your content
            }
        }

        override val itemsCount: Int
            get() = //count content

        override fun getKey(index: Int): Any = index
        override val keyToIndexMap: Map<Any, Int> = emptyMap()
        override fun getContentType(index: Int): Any? = null
    },
    //modifier = modifier
        //.padding(paddingValues)
        //.verticalScroll(state = state, flingBehavior = NoFlingBehavior)
) { constraints -> 
  //do whatever you want
}
```